# How do I sort my mailbox statistics in O365?

Tags: powershell, sorting

I am using the following code and I want to sort by TotalItemSize. I am not getting the desired results.

```
Get-Mailbox -RecipientTypeDetails usermailbox -resultsize 10 |
Get-MailboxStatistics | Sort-Object totalitemsize |
Format-Table totalitemsize
```

- This results in the following:

```
TotalItemSize
-------------
22.7 GB (24,370,512,818 bytes) 
15.95 GB (17,130,688,417 bytes)
7.84 GB (8,417,699,591 bytes)
8.659 GB (9,297,263,477 bytes)
27.36 GB (29,374,899,586 bytes)
11.29 GB (12,119,583,472 bytes)
2.103 GB (2,258,067,401 bytes)
44.15 GB (47,409,766,670 bytes)
21.08 GB (22,629,885,399 bytes)
17.97 GB (19,296,711,234 bytes)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using this:

```bash
$re = [regex] '(?<=\()[\d,]+'

Get-Mailbox -RecipientTypeDetails usermailbox -Resultsize 10 |
    Get-MailboxStatistics |
    Sort-Object { $re.Match($_.totalitemsize).Value -as [double] } |
    Format-Table totalitemsize
```

[`Sort-Object`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object?view=powershell-7.2) should be able to handle it once we capture the bytes with [`Regex.Match`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.match?view=net-7.0) and convert them to [`double`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double?view=net-7.0).

Using the data provided in the answer stored in `test.txt`:

```bash
$re = [regex] '(?<=\()[\d,]+'
Get-Content .\test.txt |
    Sort-Object { $re.Match($_).Value -as [double] }
```

The output looks like this, sorted in ascending order:

```
2.103 GB (2,258,067,401 bytes)
7.84 GB (8,417,699,591 bytes)
8.659 GB (9,297,263,477 bytes)
11.29 GB (12,119,583,472 bytes)
15.95 GB (17,130,688,417 bytes)
17.97 GB (19,296,711,234 bytes)
21.08 GB (22,629,885,399 bytes)
22.7 GB (24,370,512,818 bytes) 
27.36 GB (29,374,899,586 bytes)
44.15 GB (47,409,766,670 bytes)
```